# How to create a route with client-java-api of k8s

Tags: java, kubernetes

About the k8s java client `client-java-api`, which I picked the version of `4.0.0`. I need to create a Route so that my service has a host to access from browser.
But now the problem is, there is no api like a `createNamespacedRoute`. I create the pod by calling the `createNamespacedPod`, and the service by calling `createNamespacedService`. Pods and Services run well. And how can I create a Route with `client-java-api`?
Any advices?
THANKS!!

Comment: what do you mean with `route`?

Comment: do you mean "ingress"?

Comment: Actually, it should be ingress. But in openshift platform, there is a Route which looks a little different like ingress. Anyway, what i need is access the container via a hostname or domain name.

Comment: Solved. Openshift platform created a concept called Route for the same purpose as Ingress(K8S). Once you set an ingress, you set corresponding route and the service docker inside can be accessible.